# Stack implementation using linked list in C++

Tags: c++, linked-list, stack

I'd like some feedback for the code I wrote. I haven't programmed in C++ for two years.

```
#include <string>

#pragma once
template <class T>
class StackLinkedList
{
public:
    StackLinkedList() : m_List(nullptr), m_Size(0) {}
    ~StackLinkedList();
    void push(const T& val);
    void pop();
    T& top();
    const T& top() const;
    size_t size() const;
    bool empty() const;
private:
    struct Node;
    Node *m_List;
    size_t m_Size;
};

template <class T>
struct StackLinkedList<T>::Node
{
    T m_Val;
    Node* m_Next;
    Node(const T& val, Node* nextPtr) : m_Val(val), m_Next(nextPtr) {}
};

template<class T>
StackLinkedList<T>::~StackLinkedList()
{
    typename Node* nextNodePtr;
    for (typename Node* curNodePtr = m_List; curNodePtr != nullptr; )
    {
        nextNodePtr = curNodePtr->m_Next;
        delete curNodePtr;
        curNodePtr = nextNodePtr;
    }
}

template<class T>
void StackLinkedList<T>::push(const T& val)
{
    typename Node* newNode = new Node(val, m_List);
    m_List = newNode;
    m_Size++;
}

template<class T>
void StackLinkedList<T>::pop()
{
    if (m_List != nullptr)
    {
        typename Node* curNodePtr = m_List;
        m_List = m_List->m_Next;
        delete curNodePtr;
        m_Size--;
    }
}

template<class T>
T& StackLinkedList<T>::top()
{
    if (empty())
    {
        throw new std::string("Stack is empty");
    }
    return m_List->m_Val;
}

template<class T>
const T& StackLinkedList<T>::top() const
{
    if (empty())
    {
        throw new std::string("Stack is empty")
    }
    return m_List->m_Val;
}

template<class T>
size_t StackLinkedList<T>::size() const
{
    return m_Size;
}

template<class T>
bool StackLinkedList<T>::empty() const
{
    return m_Size == 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is quite good, actually. I have one big comment, and a few relatively minor comments.

[**RULE OF THREE**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three). Anytime you define a destructor, you want to make sure you define your copy constructor and copy assignment operators. The reason for that is the following:

```
StackLinkedList<T> stack;
stack.push(...);
stack.push(...);
{
    StackLinkedList<T> stack2 = stack;
    stack2.push(...);
    // <== stack2 deleted here
}
// <== uh-oh, stack2 deleted all the nodes, but stack still thinks
// it has valid objects that it's holding onto that it needs to delete too!
```

Your class is sorely missing:

```
StackLinkedList(const StackLinkedList& );

friend void swap(StackLinkedList&, StackLinkedList& );
StackLinkedList& operator=(StackLinkedList other) {
    swap(*this, other);
    return *this;
}
```

For more on why I suggest this way specifically, see [what is the copy-and-swap idiom](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3279543/2069064).

You didn't mention if you were using C++11 or not. If you are, you want the Rule of Five: you will also need to implement the move constructor and move assignment operator. For this class in particular, those two should be very short.

---

Other comments are minor.

**Use of `typename`**. There are places where you *need* to use `typename` and there are places where you don't. Just don't use it in those latter cases - it's just unnecessary. In your code, literally every usage of `typename` is redundant and can be omitted.

**`top()`**. The typical implementation of containers is to make operations as fast as possible. So for `top()`, that would mean not checking `empty()` - that's up to the user. Just simply return `m_List->m_Val` and note that it's just undefined behavior to call `top()` on an empty stack. If you disagree and want to throw an exception, that is of course perfectly reasonable as well - but this not the way to do it:

```
throw new std::string("Stack is empty");
```

You're throwing a `std::string*`. Anybody that catches it would have to `delete` it, otherwise you're leaking memory - and `std::string*` doesn't really convey information. If you look in [`<stdexcept>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/stdexcept), there's a better choice of exception type: [`std::out_of_range`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/out_of_range). Standard practice is to throw by value, catch by reference. So that line would be:

```
throw std::out_of_range("Stack is empty");
```

**`#pragma once`** should be the first line in your file, you have it after a different `#include`.

Comment: `Just simply return m_List->m_Val and note that it's just undefined behavior to call top() on an empty stack.` I recommend to use assert for range-checks to get more information if something breaks in debug-mode and still full-speed in release mode.

Comment: Thanks. You comments are very useful. I went over all of them and fixed the issues. One thing I don`t agree with you is the assignment operator the signature you proposed is StackLinkedList& operator=(StackLinkedList other). Isn`t it better to do StackLinkedList& operator=(const StackLinkedList& other)?